# Why Firefox show me "too much recursion" error?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm using the following code to generate an area google charts. In the code below the chart has only one point. I did it just for understand why firefox show me the "too much recursion" error. Someone can help me?

```
<?php

$equity_array = array(0);
$date_array = array(date("d/m/Y"));
$label_num = array(1);



echo"
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js'></script>
   <script type='text/javascript'>
   google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
   google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


   function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Time', 'Retorno'],";


echo"       ['" . $date_array[0] . "', " . $equity_array[0] . "], ";

echo"   ]);

        var options = {
        focusTarget: 'category',
        chartArea: {left: 70, right:50, top: 30, bottom: 50},
        series: {
         0: { color: '#469DE4' },},
              legend: 'none',
        vAxis: {textStyle:{color: '#7F7F7F'}, baselineColor: '#CCCCCC', format: '#%', gridlines: {color: 'transparent'}}, 
        fontName: 'Source Sans Pro',
        hAxis: {textStyle:{color: '#7F7F7F'}, showTextEvery:" . $label_num . "}};
        var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({pattern:'#,###%'});
        formatter.format(data, 1);

        chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>
    <div id='chart_div' style='height: 450px;'></div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You define a callback for on load:

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

which does some drawing:

```
   function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Time', 'Retorno'],";


echo"       ['" . $date_array[0] . "', " . $equity_array[0] . "], ";

echo"   ]);

        var options = {
        focusTarget: 'category',
        chartArea: {left: 70, right:50, top: 30, bottom: 50},
        series: {
         0: { color: '#469DE4' },},
              legend: 'none',
        vAxis: {textStyle:{color: '#7F7F7F'}, baselineColor: '#CCCCCC', format: '#%', gridlines: {color: 'transparent'}}, 
        fontName: 'Source Sans Pro',
        hAxis: {textStyle:{color: '#7F7F7F'}, showTextEvery:" . $label_num . "}};
        var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({pattern:'#,###%'});
        formatter.format(data, 1);

        chart.draw(data, options);
        }
```

and thus triggers the onload. You should draw the chart only once.

Comment: Thanks Lajos for your answer, but I don't understand...why you say I'm drawing the chart two times?